# Show Top ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am reading code for an app that contains 40+ ViewController. How would you know which ViewController is the current.

**What I have tried:**

1. CBIntrospect: execute a `UIAlertView` with a
   message:`NSStringFromClass([self class])`?
2. looked at adding
   something to `NotificationCenter` and act  on some method when a view
   controller is piped?
3. Using the `runtime.h` to dynamically add a
   method?

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController
{
    return [self topViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
}


- (UIViewController *)topViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController.presentedViewController == nil) {
        return viewController;
    }

    if ([viewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) viewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController       *topViewController    = [navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
        return [self topViewController:topViewController];
    }

    UIViewController *presentedViewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewController:presentedViewController];
}
```

Comment: Where would you call topViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I often use [self.window recursiveDescription] to print all UIViews through my app. This is not VC, but can be also useful to you.

Just set the breakpoint everywhere you need and type (replace window with your key "UIWindow"):

```
[window recursiveDescription]
```

You'll see common result:

```
<UIWindow: 0xc0275c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc027b20>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xc0276e0>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0xc0196b0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc022fa0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc019790>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0xc011a60; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xc00ebd0>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xb34ab10; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xb34abe0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xc44a7c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xc44a820>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0xdb4a000; frame = (0 0; 320 468); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc449ac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc448550>; contentOffset: {-0, -63}>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0xc44a440; frame = (0 0; 320 468); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xc44a510>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <WorkspaceCell: 0xc023a50; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xc00cad0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xc02c400; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc02c980>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc02c610>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xc022980; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc02d2f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc02b0c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xc0233f0; frame = (15 7; 29 29); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc0291e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xc0262e0; frame = (60 11; 240 21); text = 'Alterplay'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc0276a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xc023130; frame = (15 7; 29 29); text = 'A'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc0231d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xc02e4e0; frame = (0 43.5; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xc02e5b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xc02e850; frame = (0 0; 320 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xc02e8c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xc449210; frame = (0 465.5; 320 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc4494a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xc449680; frame = (316.5 414; 3.5 55); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc449760>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xc44a850; frame = (0 518; 320 50); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc44a8b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0xc4458a0; frame = (75 14; 172 22); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc4459d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xb359ce0; frame = (27.5 4; 117 14); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb359560>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xc44a9f0; frame = (0 468; 320 50); autoresize = LM+RM+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc44aa50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0xc447b10; frame = (101 10; 119 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc447c00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0xb34c1a0; frame = (32 3; 55 24); text = 'Logout'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb34c2b0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xc44ab00; frame = (0 424; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc44ab90>>
   |    | <UINavigationBar: 0xc019980; frame = (0 20; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc01b9f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc019ae0>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackground: 0xc01a180; frame = (0 -20; 320 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc01a2b0>>
   |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0xc01c0d0; frame = (0 0; 320 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0xc01dca0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropEffectView: 0xc01e6b0; frame = (0 0; 320 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CABackdropLayer: 0xc01e970>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xc01f2a0; frame = (0 0; 320 64); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc01f400>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xc01a540; frame = (0 64; 320 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc01a610>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationItemView: 0xc023490; frame = (111.5 8; 97.5 27); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc023570>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xc023920; frame = (0 3; 97.5 22); text = 'Workspaces'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc023a20>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0xc029150; frame = (8 12; 12.5 20.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc029240>>
```